# embedding python

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, python-embedding

Im trying to call python functions from C code, and i followed a sample from [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.2/ext/pure-embedding.html)

I also have the correct include file directries, library directries, and linked the python32.lib (im using python 32) however the error was that python/C APIs such as PyString_FromString, PyInt_FromLong, PyInt_AsLong are undefined (error in the debugger)

this is strange because im also using other APIs, but they're all fine...

whats the problem here??

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc;
    PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;
    int i;

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: call pythonfile funcname [args]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    Py_Initialize();
    pName = PyString_FromString(argv[1]);
    /* Error checking of pName left out */

    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);

    if (pModule != NULL) {
        pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
        /* pDict is a borrowed reference */
```

Py_Initialize(), PyImport_Import(), PyModule_GetDict() all work fine, but not PyString_FromString...

Comment: I really think that the function PyString_FromString was renamed to PyBytes_FromString into the Python 3.x.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The example code you used is for ancient Python version, 2.3.2. Python 3.x line introduced a number of incompatibilites not only in the language but in the C API as well.

The functions you mention simply no longer exist in Python 3.2.

`PyString_` functions were renamed to `PyBytes_`.

`PyInt_` functions are gone, `PyLong_` should be used instead.

Here's the same example that you've used but for Python 3:

[5.3. Pure Embedding](http://docs.python.org/py3k/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding)

Note that it's using `PyUnicode_` instead of `PyString_/PyBytes_`. In many places where Python 2.x used byte strings, Python 3.x uses unicode strings.

By the way, I usually use this page to look up all possible calls:

[Index – P](http://docs.python.org/py3k/genindex-P.html)

Comment: so i followed ur suggestion and it worked. now i want to test it using the documentation example you've provided. do i go into the .exe directry and cmd 'call multiply multiply 3 2' ??

Comment: I think so, yes, assuming the exe file is called `call`. If you get stuck, ask a separate question.