# Xcode gives error while using Python.framework in iOS ,undefined symbol for architecture i386

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, xcode

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

> "_PyInt_AsLong", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>
> "_PyInt_FromLong", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>
> "_PyString_FromString", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error:

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Wild guess, you are trying to compile Python 2 code with Python 3.  Reason for wild guess = `_PyInt_FromLong` is replaced with `PyLong_FromLong`.  See http://python3porting.com/cextensions.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229597/embedding-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing

1. PyUnicode_AsUTF8  or PyUnicode_FromString for _PyString_FromString
2. PyLong_AsLong for _PyInt_AsLong
3. PyLong_FromLong for _PyInt_FromLong

solved my problem.