# When running code, error says undefined symbol: PyInt_AsLong

Tags: python, .so

I'm using my raspberry pi to run a HUB 75 LED matrix. 
I have to import a library to do that, but when I run my code, something in that library seems to throw up an error...is there anything I can do about that? The file seems to have a .so extension, when I looked...how might I open that?
I am aware my code may look a bit silly, but I can't work it out if the imported library won't work.
Here's the code:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

from rgbmatrix import Adafruit_RGBMatrix

matrix = Adafruit_RGBmatrix(32,1)

image = Image.new("1", (32, 32))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

image = open(smileyForMatrix.bmp)
image.load()
matrix.SetImage(image.im.id, n, 1)
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/matrixLED/matrixImage.py", line 5, in <module>
from rgbmatrix import Adafruit_RGBMatrix
ImportError: /home/pi/Desktop/matrixLED/rgbmatrix.so: undefined symbol: PyInt_AsLong
```

Comment: Which interpreter are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/mfranberg/libplinkio/commit/58da1206a4bc7491c2a894a632b411762ae83407 I hope this link helps you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [embedding python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229597/embedding-python)

Comment: I'm using IDLE @brunsgaard

Comment: I looked at the Github link... I could try to put this bit                                             #define PyInt_AsLong(x) (PyLong_AsLong((x))) into the .so file...

Comment: SORRY -  it was a typo. Should have been  from rgbmatrix import Adafruit_RGBmatrix as in lower case after Adafruit_RGB.